# Reusing modules in angular2 fails

Tags: angular, typescript

Am developing an angular2 website and i have a root module and a sub level module but whatever modules i include in the root module i have to reinclude in the sub level module hence not really reusable

This is hat i have

in the app module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       ComingSoonComponent,
     ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HomepageModule,  //included the homepage module
      OwlModule

   ],
 providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
   export class AppModule { }
```

Now in the homepage module

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
        CommonModule,
         OwlModule//already in the app module
    ],
    declarations: [HomepageComponent]
  })
 export class HomepageModule { }
```

The owl module is imported twice so that it works but if i import only in the app module then i get an error that

```
 If 'owl-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

What could i be missing out since in an application involving multiple modules this can become abit tiresome having to duplicate imports

Answer (score 1):

remove it from the `AppModule` and   add it to the imports/exports arrays of `HomepageModule`:

HomepageModule :

```
    @NgModule({
       imports: [
            CommonModule,
            OwlModule
        ],
       exports: [
           OwlModule
        ],
        declarations: [HomepageComponent]
      })
     export class HomepageModule { }
```

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       ComingSoonComponent,
     ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HomepageModule

   ],
 providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
   export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This works but imagine you have more than 5 sublevel modules will i have to add it as exports in all sublevel modules considering that the app module is the main(root) module

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI in this case just duplicate them like you did because duplicating modules is normal, take for example `CommonModule` that contains directives `ngIf` and `ngFor`, including this  module in your AppModule doesn't mean that `ngIf` and `ngFor` are available in other components of sublevel modules,you have to include it in sublevel modules. this is just an example you're already doing this module  duplication when you include the BrowserModule that exports CommonModule in AppModule and you include CommonModule again in sublevel modules.

Comment: I agree but you can create a shared module and add all the exports that other modules use. Then, you just import shared module in target module instead of importing 1 to infinite modules